# slf4j multiple bindings with Mahout on Amazon EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, lucene, mahout, amazon-emr

I'm running a mahout job on Amazon EMR and getting the following exception:

```
ArrayUtil.oversize(II)I
attempt_201311181700_0002_m_000000_0: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
attempt_201311181700_0002_m_000000_0: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201311181700_0002_m_000000_0: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201311181700_0002/jars/job.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201311181700_0002_m_000000_0: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
attempt_201311181700_0002_m_000000_0: SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Error: org.apache.lucene.util.ArrayUtil.oversize(II)I
attempt_201311181700_0002_m_000000_1: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
attempt_201311181700_0002_m_000000_1: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201311181700_0002_m_000000_1: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201311181700_0002/jars/job.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201311181700_0002_m_000000_1: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
attempt_201311181700_0002_m_000000_1: SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Error: org.apache.lucene.util.ArrayUtil.oversize(II)I
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.collocations.llr.CollocDriver.generateCollocations(CollocDriver.java:238)
    at org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.collocations.llr.CollocDriver.generateAllGrams(CollocDriver.java:187)
    at org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.DictionaryVectorizer.createTermFrequencyVectors(DictionaryVectorizer.java:184)
    at clustering.AmazonClusteringDriver.main(AmazonClusteringDriver.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:187)
```

I excluded the slf4j dependency in mahout dependency; however, it doesn't solve the problem. So, where is the problem?

Comment: The revised pom file get rid of the multiple binding error; however,ArrayUtil.oversize(II)I method still has problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very wrong place to ask this.

You should be asking this on the Mahout developer mailing list.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Mailing+Lists,+IRC+and+Archives#MailingLists%2CIRCandArchives-MahoutUserList